# Generating a maximal geometric progression of integers

Tags: python, performance, mathematics

I'm working on a program that generates a maximal geometric progression of at least 3 integers when given a number that the greatest value shouldn't exceed.

My current code works, and it's quick(ish) with small numbers, but anything past 100 takes far longer than I'd like, as I need to calculate numbers in ranges from \$10^7\$ to \$10^{20}\$.

If possible, I'd like to eliminate using `Thread`s, as Python's are known for their lackluster performance.

```
from itertools import izip,islice,tee,takewhile
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

#initialize the queue
g=Queue()

#checks that all values end with `.0`
def int_check(l):
    for i in l:
        if i-int(i)!=0: return False
    return True

#checks if a generated list fits the criteria
def check(obj):
    cpy0,cpy1=tee(obj)
    iter0,iter1=tee(float(x)/y for x,y in izip(cpy0,islice(cpy1,1,None)))
    return all(x==y for x,y in izip(iter0,islice(iter1,1,None))) and len(obj)>2 and int_check(obj)

#thread target
def calc(s,n,q):
    for r in xrange(125,n*100+1,5):
        t=[s]
        while t[-1]<=n:
            t.extend([t[-1]*((0.0+r)/100)])

        if check(t):
            q.put(takewhile(lambda i: i<=n,t))

#starts threads, calculates final value, and manages queue
def geo_prog(n):
    #Queue -> list
    def dump_queue(q):
        q.put('EOQ')
        res=[]
        return (i for i in iter(q.get,'EOQ'))

    for s in xrange(int(n/4),int(n*0.8)+1):
        t=Thread(target=calc,args=(s,n,g))
        t.start()
        t.join()

    return max(map(sum,dump_queue(g)))

#ex usage
print geo_prog(100)
```

**Examples**

```
geo_prog(4) -> 7.0
geo_prog(10) -> 15.0
geo_prog(12) -> 21.0
geo_prog(100) -> 240.0
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I tried `geom_prog(16)` which gave me `28` which is `4 + 8 + 16`. I was hoping for `37` (`9 + 12 + 16` with factor `4/3`).

Comment: I have rolled back the last slew of edits, because they invalidated the given answer. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Also, after posting please don't make any edits to your code.  It can mess up review in progress as well as invalidate answers.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk, Vogel612 already mentioned this

Comment: @Inori not even if you have answers.   Just avoid editing *at all*.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk, I'm well aware now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No threading, please!!

First of all, get rid of the threads all-together. That should speed things up: Python threads are (sort-of) fine when things are blocking on IO, but in this case everything is CPU-based, and that means the GIL (global interpreter lock) makes sure that only one thread is running.

Also, the following code is a bit curious:

```
for s in xrange(int(n/4),int(n*0.8)+1):
    t=Thread(target=calc,args=(s,n,g))
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

I know that threading is a bit of a problem anyway here, but I would just like to comment on this specifically: by writing `t.join()` you are waiting on the thread to finish before starting the next iteration. This gets read of the threading all together, as there will only be two threads alive at a given time: 1 worker thread, and the main thread waiting on the worker to die.

I'd suggest writing it as:

```
threads = []
for s in iterable:
    t = Thread(...)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

## Naming and describing

Ok, with threading out of the way, I'm having a difficult time finding what the application is supposed to do.

It does something with an `n`, and each worker with an `s` and an `n`. What are those? The code could be a lot clearer in this regard.

Anyway, let us clean things up a bit first, and maybe I can find a pattern to help you improve the algorithm.

## Performance

### Checking for integer-valued lists.

Let's start looking at `int_check`.

```
def int_check(l):
    for i in l:
        if i-int(i)!=0: return False
    return True
```

You're checking if a number is integral by doing a lengthy calculation. Why not just

if i.is_integer(): return False

? Available since Python 2.6. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer

Also, looping is expensive! Suggestion, use a comprehension together with the `all`.

```
def int_check(l):
    return all(i.is_integer() for i in l)
```

You should also name it better:

```
def is_integer_list(l):
    return all(i.is_integer() for i in l)
```

### Useless duplication of lists

Let's look at the following code:

```
def check(obj):
    cpy0,cpy1=tee(obj)
    iter0,iter1=tee(float(x)/y for x,y in izip(cpy0,islice(cpy1,1,None)))
    return all(x==y for x,y in izip(iter0,islice(iter1,1,None))) and len(obj)>2 and int_check(obj)
```

First of all, let us do some short-circuiting. You're doing a lot of logic to see if it is a nice geometric progression, and after all the hard work, you check some very easy conditions. Turn that around!

```
def check(obj):
    if len(obj) <= 2 or not int_check(obj):
        return False
    cpy0,cpy1=tee(obj)
    iter0,iter1=tee(float(x)/y for x,y in izip(cpy0,islice(cpy1,1,None)))
    return all(x==y for x,y in izip(iter0,islice(iter1,1,None)))
```

I'm doubtful of you using `tee` for this. But I don't see a better builtin for it either. But I see a lot of logic here which I'd like to separate a bit more:

```
def steps(iterable):  # Needs better name, please help me!
    iterator = iter(iterable)  # Cast iterable to iterator.
    cur = next(iterator)
    for val in iterator:
        yield cur, val
        cur = val
```

A quick test to see that it does what we want.

```
>>> list(steps(range(10)))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)]
```

Using that, we get

```
def check(obj):
    if len(obj) <= 2 or not int_check(obj):
        return False
    ratios = (float(x)/y for x, y in steps(obj))
    return all(x == y for x, y in steps(ratios))
```

Don't know if it's faster, but at least it is more readable! And I expect faster. But the main gain might be in the next section

### The main loop

Your code was written as

```
def calc(s,n,q):
    for r in xrange(125,n*100+1,5):
        t=[s]
        while t[-1]<=n:
            t.extend([t[-1]*((0.0+r)/100)])

        if check(t):
            q.put(takewhile(lambda i: i<=n,t))
```

Since I want to get rid of the threading, I'll assume `q` is a list instead of a queue.

```
def calc(s,n,q):
    for r in xrange(125,n*100+1,5):
        t=[s]
        while t[-1]<=n:
            t.extend([t[-1]*((0.0+r)/100)])

        if check(t):
            q.append(takewhile(lambda i: i<=n,t))
```

(In reality I'd rather yield the results instead of adding to a queue. Anyhow, I'm shelving that for now)

#### takewhile vs slicing.

In the `q.put` you write takewhile. By the `while` loop above, you already know that will be all but the last value.

So, write

```
q.append(t[:-1])
```

Or, even

```
t.pop()
q.append(t)
```

That should be faster, because now the `lambda i: i <= n` doesn't have to be executed anymore.

#### Useless recalculation

Having written the above loop now as

```
def calc(s,n,q):
    for r in xrange(125,n*100+1,5):
        t=[s]
        while t[-1]<=n:
            t.extend([t[-1]*((0.0+r)/100)])

        if check(t):
            t.pop()
            q.append(t)
```

We can turn our focus to the expression `t.extend(...)` above:

```
    for r in xrange(125,n*100+1,5):
        t=[s]
        while t[-1]<=n:
            t.extend([t[-1]*((0.0+r)/100)])
```

Now in each iteration of the while loop, `(0.0+r)/100` gets recalculated. Why not

```
    for r in xrange(125, n*100+1,5):
        r_ = float(r) / 100
        t=[s]
        while t[-1]<=n:
            t.extend([t[-1]*r_)
```

## Incorrect algorithm

The worst part, I think, is that your code works by trying different ratios, and will miss some geometric sequences.

For instance, the sequence

```
81, 90, 100  # r == 100.0 / 90.0 == 90.0 / 81.0 (approx 1.1111111)
```

While your code will only try 1.25, 1.30, 1.35, ... .

Now, maybe there is some high-level mathematical proof that the solution will always involve a ratio which can be expressed as `(125 + 5*k)/100`, but I don't think so.

I would suggest turning the problem up-side-down. The following is an O(n^2 * log(n)) suggestion (estimated, but I think correct. Maybe even O(n^2)).

```
for x1 in xrange(1, n):
    for x2 in xrange(x1, n):
        # Using that
        #     x1 == a
        #     x2 == a * r
        # we get that
        #     r == x2 / x1
        ratio = float(x2) / x1
        # Continue as before, starting from t = [x1, x2]
```

## Another point of incorrectness

In `check`, you check that the length is > 2, but *then* you filter on `<=n`. This should be the other way around.

## A tiny suggestion.

Floating point arithmetic is challenging for problems like these. Maybe look into the fractions module?

```
from fractions import Fraction

...
ratio = Fraction(x2, x1)
...
```

Now, Fraction does not have an `is_integer`, but you can do the following:

```
>>> Fraction(5, 1).denominator == 1
True
```

Hope that all helps.

## Corner cases

As an addendum, here are some cases your code flagged incorrectly:

```
>>> geom_prog(16)
28.0  # 4 + 8 + 16
```

but it should be at least 37: 9 + 12 + 16.

```
>>> geom_prog(100)
244.0  # 64 + 80 + 100
```

but it should be at least 271: 81 + 90 + 100 (maybe even more, but doubt it).

Comment: FYI: My review was based on an earlier revision. Most still holds, though, except for the part about when the length-check occurs.

Comment: PEP 8 specifically warns against using `l` as a variable name because it is so similar to  `1`.  You didn't comment on that in `int_check()`.  One more thing: your solution for that function uses a generator expression, not a comprehension.

Comment: excellent tips. And yes, I realized that the algorithm in the previous versions was off, which I fixed.
As an addition, type juggling via `(0.0+r)/100` is faster than casting with `float()`.
For variable names, `r` is the ratio in use, and `n` is the maximum number (which I suppose I could replace with `m`)